# Extension Manager calls load events only once in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, vs-extensibility

I want to hook up to any kind of event triggered before the Extension Manager is loaded (Loaded, Activated, etc.), using Handlers to execute methods I wrote.

I tried all of them, and they get executed when the Extension Manager is rendered the first time. However, if I close it and open it again, the events are not triggered.

Is this common behavior in VS2015 (unlike in previous versions)? Is there any workaround to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.

Until VS2015, the Extension Manager shared the same Window, but this newer version uses a different window every time the Extension Manager is opened. This is why a re-setup of the window event handlers is needed in order to get the events triggered.